# Entity not being populated in controller DXA .Net

Tags: dxa, component, dxa-net, dxa-1.8

I'm having some issues recovering a Tridion component content in a controller in my DXA project.

The component schema is called AutocompleteResults and it has 2 fields:

- hotels: Component Link of Hotel (a schema including name, category, email... and other text fields) allowing multiple values.
- destinations: Component Link of City (a schema including name and country) allowing multiple values.

I created some components using the schema Hotel and some using City. Then, I created a component AutocompleteResults using the schema AutocompleteResults, and added the hotel and city components as component links.

I also created a component template adding "Default Component Template Finish Actions" and "Render Component Presentations" and vinculating the schema AutocompleteResults. I configured it like this:

[image: ComponentTemplate configuration]

I also created a page template Autocomplete adding "Render Page Content" and "Default Page Template Finish Actions" and configured it like this:

[image: PageTemplate configuration]

Then, I created a page Autocomplete inheriting from the above page template and adding the presentation Component/Component template created before.

[image: AutocompletePage1]

[image: AutocompletePage2]

I have published the page, publish settings and components (this last ones just in case), but I can't get the information in my DXA .NET project.

This is the controller and the action I created, but entity is not being populated:

[image: Controller]

[image: NullEntity]

The view AutocompleteResults referenced in the component template is also created, and it's registered in the CoreAreaRegistration (I've tried also without the last parameter "Page").

[image: CoreAreaRegistration]

The model AutocompleteResults has the same structure as the schema of the component in Tridion:

[image: AutocompleteResultsModel]

Could anyone help me to see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Mer

Comment: Can you try below one on your Area Registration page and confirm - 
 RegisterViewModel("AutocompleteResults", typeof(AutocompleteResults), controllerName: "AutocompleteResults");

Comment: @SayantanBasu thank you for your quick response, but it's still not working...

Comment: Your template needs to be DD4T/DXA, and I think you are using the "Default" TBBs used for html generation... You need the TBBs that generate JSON/XML instead, so DXA can read the models....

Comment: Anything interesting in the DXA log file (if you set log level to DEBUG)?

Comment: What does your AutoCompleteResults Schema look like? In particular: what is the Root Element Name and what are the field names?

Comment: @RickPannekoek here you have the schema: https://hastebin.bluekiri.com/osujunatoy.xml

Comment: OK, the View Model Type and its annotations seem to match your CM Schema. One remark: the SemanticEntity annotation doesn't make sense: schema.org does not define a semantic type called AutocompleteResults.  Anyways, this is not expected to interfere with the CM mapping.  Please check your DXA log file for hints why the semantic mapping isn't working.

Comment: @RickPannekoek, the only thing I see in the logs is this: "HTML design is not published nor does file 'C:\project\system\assets\version.json' exist on disk. Setting version to v0.0"

Comment: Did you set log level to DEBUG? I expect to see diagnostic output if fields can't be mapped. See line 486 in https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.8/Sdl.Web.Tridion/Mapping/DefaultModelBuilder.cs

Comment: Yes, I set it my webconfig like this: <add key="log-level" value="DEBUG" /> The content in the log has this: https://hastebin.bluekiri.com/gutevituce.pas

Comment: The log level for the DXA log file is set in `Log.config`;  the setting in `Web.config` only applies to CIL logging (in `cd_client.log`)

Comment: @RickPannekoek I've changed it in the Log.config and reloaded the page and I only get this in the log https://hastebin.bluekiri.com/hoforuwine.py  I think there are no mapping errors but the object keeps null.

Answer (score 1):

Your log file reveals that there is an HTTP Request directly to the Entity Action of your custom Entity Controller. That is not the way that Entity Controllers are normally used and no CM Model Mapping will occur in that manner.

Entity Controllers are normally invoked as part of the Page rendering flow. You can let your custom Entity Controller inherit from `EntityController` and override the `EnrichModel` method to dynamically populate your Entity Model (after regular CM model mapping happened).

I’m not sure how you expect your Controller to be used and what is generating the HTTP Request on your Controller’s Entity Action?

**UPDATE:**

If your Component is part of a Page, you don’t need a custom Controller in order to make CM model mapping work.

If you want to retrieve the Component as a separate entity, you will have to use a dynamic CT, so the Component gets published as separate entity (Dynamic Component Presentation). DXA currently does not have a built-in Controller action to retrieve Entity Models (for DCPs) separately, but you can create a custom Controller action to do that. Your custom Controller (inherited from `BaseController`) can use `ContentProvider.GetEntityModel` to obtain the Entity Model for the DCP.

Comment: What I really need is to recover the content of my AutocompleteResults component created in Tridion and map it into a model. Is there another way to do that without a custom Entity Controller? I was just testing this option by calling the controller directly from the browser.

Comment: Updated the Answer with some more information.

Comment: I've tried adding this in my controller https://imgur.com/neGJbun, but I get this error: "No Component Template data available for DCP 'tcm:47-724/tcm:47-723-32'. Republish the DCP to ensure it uses the new DD4T 2.0 DCP format." I've tried republishing the component template, the component, the publish settings... but I always get that error. Could you check if my component template it's well configured? Thank you very much for your patience! https://imgur.com/0nE4eQO https://imgur.com/zDnvIlk https://imgur.com/2guGeFv

Comment: Your CT should be set to “dynamic” (4th dropdown from the top labelled “Las presentaciones de componente ...”). Then, when you Publish the Component, you will see that a DCP gets resolved (next to or instead of Pages which contain the Component).

Comment: Hi again. I made that change after some research before you tell me and it made no difference :(. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your component template needs to be dynamic and not published as part of the page. And you will need to use default DXA TBBs that will output json format to the Broker database.

Comment: It should work fine with embedded CPs too.

Comment: What is the default DXA TBBs, @Stefan Klasnic? Do you mean I should remove "Default Component FInish Actions" and "Render Component Content" and use a DD4T Template? Which one, "DD4T.Templates.Merged", "Generate Dynamic Component"...?

Comment: No, "Render Page Content" and "Render Component Content" are the default DXA TBBs.  These take care of rendering the Page/Component as JSON (either DD4T JSON or DXA R2 JSON in DXA 2.0).

Comment: Then I guess if I've already added "Default Component FInish Actions" and "Render Component Content", the template configuration is fine.